# Background Music not replaying in iOS8 when entering foreground

Tags: ios8, avaudioplayer, appdelegate

Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
    ((MyScene *)view.scene).gamePaused = YES;

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
}
```

Here is my code from the AppDelegate.m file. Whenever I exit the app and re-enter, the background music for my game won't start replaying again. This code worked fine for iOS7 but not longer does for iOS8, I am wondering how to fix this issue.

Comment: I don't do developing for mobile platforms, but shouldn't you try using an updated version of the SDK for iOS 8?

Comment: @zyboxinternational what do you mean by that? sorry to sound like an amateur.

Comment: As in, iOS 8 probably requires an updated SDK to enable access to new features, and to provide compatibility with existing features.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/ios8/

Comment: I am pretty sure I have the latest SDK, I am using xcode6. I just want to know why the code (that worked for iOS7) no longer works for iOS8, do I have to rewrite all my code in Swift?

Comment: You need Xcode 6.0.1 (iOS 8).

Comment: Sorry it is 6.0.1, but do you know how to sort the issue out. The music is no longer playing when i enter the foreground. This message: "Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session." pops up in the log box when running the application and exiting the app

Comment: Ok, the way to fix this issue is to implement [audioplayer pause]; in your pause method for exiting the app and [audioplayer prepareToPlay]; [audioplayer play]; in your resume method for entering the app.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue.  I also have pause upon exit and suspend audio - worked great in iOS7 - but ios 8 does not work.. I have tried both xcode6 and beta xcode6.1 - on ios7 and ios8 devices.  ios7 never has an issue and works as intended- but ios8 gives me issues, does not pause or suspend audio.. Really annoying!!

Answer (score 0):

selecting *Audio and Airplay* item in **Background Modes**, this works for me.